# Pass array in HTML method parameters javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, methods, parameters

I know this is an easy one, but I can't find exactly what I am looking for. I was wondering if it is possible to pass an array into a method as a parameter, but through HTML. If it is possible I think it would be something like this:

```
<img src="img.png" alt="picture" onclick="thisMethod1(['Facebook','Twitter'])"/>
```

The javascript would look something like this:

```
function thisMethod1(socialArray)
{
     //use this array
}
```

Is this correct?
**The reason I am asking is because there is an error in my code and I am trying to find it.**

Comment: Post the real code and someone might find the problem. I suspect this question will get downvoted and maybe put on hold as it stands.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it should work, as this demonstrates:

```
<script>
function thisMethod1(socialArray)
{
    alert(socialArray);
}
</script>

<img src="img.png" alt="picture" onclick="thisMethod1(['Facebook','Twitter'])"/>
```

If the image is inside a link, then clicking it might cause the link to submit, so that may be causing you to think there's an error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though best practice says not to use inline code (in the tag).